# How to express in linear algebra notation the operation of scaling a matrix by each element of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Define vector
${\mathbf{a}} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  a_{1} \\ 
  a_{2} \\
\vdots\\
a_{n}
\end{array}} \right)$,
and matrix ${\mathbf{B}} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c c c c}}
  b_{11} & b_{12} & \dots &  b_{1m}\\ 
  b_{21} & b_{22} & \dots &  b_{2m}\\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  b_{n1} & b_{n2} & \dots & \ b_{nm}
\end{array}} \right)$, I would like to express in linear algebra notation, ${\mathbf{B}}$ scaled by each element of ${\mathbf{a}}$, i.e, $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c c c c}}
  a_{1}*b_{11} & a_{1}*b_{12} & \dots &  a_{1}*b_{1m}\\ 
  a_{2}*b_{21} & a_{2}*b_{22} & \dots &  a_{2}*b_{2m}\\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  a_{n}*b_{n1} & a_{n}*b_{n2} & \dots & \ a_{n}*b_{nm}
\end{array}} \right)$.

Answer (score 2):

$(B^tA_n)^t = A_nB$ where $A_n$ is a diagonal matrix having diagonal $a_1, a_2,...,a_n$.

Comment: By the way if you REALLY wanted to do everything using just vectors you could obtain $A_n$ from $\sum_{k=1}^n \langle a,e_k \rangle I_{kk}$ where $e_k$ are the basis vectors and $I_{kk}$ is the basis matrix having $1$ on the $kk$-th place and zero elsewhere.

Comment: By the way, this is simply $A_nB$.

Comment: @Rahul yea thanks man i was in a hurry when i gave that answer so didn't think it through much, edited ;)